# "one of these" or "one of those"

Tags: pronouns

I'm in a restaurant. I see something I'd like **in the menu**, but I don't know what it's called.
I point to it and say:

> Can I have one of **these**, please?

or I should say:

> Can I have one of **those**, please?

**Update:**

Can we use "those" with items that **are close to speaker**?

Comment: Did you check the definitions of *these* and *those*? Also you don't say where it is.

Comment: I discuss this very topic under a related question [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/difference-between-this-and-that/2839#2839).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "this" and "that"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/difference-between-this-and-that)

Comment: @user3169, yes, and I update the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the items are in some way near you (actually near you, or you are pointing to a picture or a menu that you are holding), you can use *these*.

But you can always use *those*, whether they are near you or not.

Answer (score 4):

Weirdly enough, that depends on how close said item is to you. Say you have a plate right in front of you, you would say

> "One of these please"

If the item in question is a few feet or more away from you, you would instead say,

> "One of those please"

Use "these" for items that are very close, and "those" for items further away

Comment: I would say so too. But you can also think about 'these' referring to some certain things. While 'those' is or can be used to generalise something. But I would say the range indicator is more reliable.