# "It" "this" difference

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between "this" and "it" in this context when pointing at something? For example, I am pointing at something near me,  or I am holding it in my hand and say "How much is this?" or "How much is it?" I often see "it" instead of "this" in children's books and videos. Do they mean the same thing in such context only?
https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=tNK0ToOgntw#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This" is a demonstrative pronoun and "it" is a personal pronoun.

When pointing at something you would use a demonstrative pronount. E.g. **This** is my car.

A personal pronoun replaces either a subject or an object. Before you can replace something you would need to mention it first. E.g. I want to buy this shirt. How much is **it**?

Also have a look at this post: [it VS. this Vs. that](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159475/it-vs-this-vs-that)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking specifically about the context of pointing to something, it's more natural to use a demonstrative pronoun (this, that) when you first refer to it.

> Excuse me, how much is this?  (*pointing to something close*)
> What is that over there?  (*pointing*)

You can follow up by using 'it' to refer to the thing, having established it as the topic.

> How much is this? Is it a genuine leather wallet? Or is it plastic?
> How much is that? The necklace over there. Could you show it to me? It's very unusual!