# I think, that is or that was(parallelism)

Tags: grammar, parallelism

Suppose you were chatting with your English teacher **online via Skype** or the like, and then it suddenly **was disconnected**, which was more likely your connection problem and not your teacher's, furthermore, **you** **reconnected** it and you said:

> **"I think** that **is** my network provider's connection problem, not yours."

Or

> **"I think** that **was** my network provider's connection problem, not yours."

Regarding *parallelism*, sentence #1 complies with the rule, but I believe it is more appropriate to use *past helping verb* like in sentence #2.

Which is correct between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you are really referring to the "connection" or the "problem". In:

> I think that **was** my network provider's connection *problem*, not yours.

the "problem" has (hopefully) ended, so you would use past tense.

However, the "connection" (the basic service provided by the ISP) continues to exist in the present. So in that context present tense would be OK.

> I think that **is** my network provider's *connection* problem, not yours.

Comment: This is just my opinion, if **''that is''** is used in the context of what you are explaining, then should it be **''this is''** instead?

Comment: @JohnA - "that is" and "this is" can often be used interchangeably. Check out the [Them, These, and Those story](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/difference-between-this-and-that/2839#2839) on an earlier, related ELL question.

Comment: @J.R., I have a question, why did you capitalize the word **''english''** as my **''english teacher''** where in fact it is as adjective here? Just a query if it's ok.

Comment: @JohnA - _English_, when referring to the language, is always spelled with a capital 'E'. You can see [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381/when-should-the-word-english-be-capitalized) for more information.