# Difference between this and that as a pronoun

Tags: difference

We use **"that"** when we refer back to the word/sentence/clause mentioned, e.g, *"Do you see that?"* (where **that** refers to the thing which I or you mentioned before).

But we also use **"this"** to refer back to word/sentence/clause mentioned, e.g, "*Will you be present at this enquiry?*" (where **this** refers to the enquiry about which we are talking); or *"How will you find this man?"* (where **this** is a man who is not present at the moment).

So what is the actual difference between them in this content??

Comment: Related [Difference between “this” and “that”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/2838/9161)

Answer (score 1):

If a thing is a physical object, and you are showing it to someone, you use this:

- What do you think of this article? [showing someone the article]
- What do you think of that article? [the one previously mentioned or away from you,say, on a table.]

BUT: How will you find this or that man is slightly different.

- How will you find this man? **The one presently being discussed.**
- How will you find that man? **The one discussed previously or earlier in a conversation.**
- How will you find the man? **The man** can also be used here.

That is the slight difference with regard to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, **this** and **that** can be used interchangeably.

- *"Will you be present at **this** enquiry?"*
- *"Will you be present at **that** enquiry?"*

In both cases, it is expected that the specific enquiry is already known to both the speaker and the listener.

- "How will you find **this** man?"
- "How will you find **that** man?"

Again, it is expected that the specific person (or category of person) is already known to both parties.

There is a possible subtle difference in the case of your first example, though:

- "Do you see **that**?"
- "Do you see **this**?"

Again, both *can* be used interchangeably, but it is more likely that someone would use **this** if the speaker expects the listener to approach the same location as the speaker, so it can be seen from the viewpoint/position of the speaker; and **that** if both the speaker and listener should be able to see the same thing from their respective positions.

But, in most cases, I consider them interchangeable.