# What's the plural of "that x of a y"?

Tags: idioms, plural-forms

> But that did not solve his problem, his mother's birthday was next
>   week, he had counted on Arsenal beating Manchester and if **that idiot
>   of a referee** had not awarded that idiotic penalty.

I am wondering what's the plural form of the bolded part. Is it "these idiots of referees"? It doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 2):

### There is no good plural equivalent

The book [The Mental Corpus: How Language is Represented in the Mind](https://books.google.com/books?id=dJi0zqwIxuAC&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=%22those+idiots+of%22) explains why there isn't one. "Those [plural] of [plural]" is the least bad of all the options, but it's extremely rarely used.

Instead, you can just call them *those stupid referees* or even *those dumbass referees*.

(Also note that the plurals go *this*->*these* and *that*->*those*, but [switching *these* and *those* usually works anyways](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/2839/41273).)

Comment: Can I ask how you were able to get that perfect source for this query? Like, how did you know where to look?

Comment: @AIQ It's the 5th result when I search Google for `"those idiots of"` (including the quotes). This may have something to do with Google's [search personalization](https://www.wsoaonline.com/does-your-internet-history-effect-google-search-results/), but I'm not sure.